# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity and java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I am doing a project which includes: Splash screen >> onboarding fragment 1 >> onboarding fragment 2 >> onboarding fragment 3 >> Send OTP screen >> Verify OTP screen >> Dashboard

So, in onboarding fragment 3 screen I have added a button "Get Started" and in Send OTP screen i have added a button "Get OTP".

So, when I click on "Get Started" button it navigates to Send OTP screen but when I click on "Get OTP" button it comes back to onboarding fragment 3 screen instead of going to Verify OTP screen.

This is the **error in logcat**:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dsproject/com.example.dsproject.verificationOTPtwo}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
```

This is my `onboardingfragment3.java` code:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_on_boarding3, container,false);

        btn = root.findViewById(R.id.get_started_button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(requireActivity().getApplicationContext(), sendOTPone.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
        return root;
    }
```

This is my `sendotp.java` code:

```
getotpbutton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!enternumber.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                if ((enternumber.getText().toString().trim()).length()==10){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),verificationOTPtwo.class);
                    intent.putExtra("mobile",enternumber.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(sendOTPone.this,"Please enter correct number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(sendOTPone.this, "Enter mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

This is my verificationOTPtwo.java code:

```
package com.example.dsproject;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class verificationOTPtwo extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText inputnumber1, inputnumber2, inputnumber3, inputnumber4, inputnumber5, inputnumber6;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verification_otptwo);

        Button verifybuttonclick = findViewById(R.id.buttongetotp);

        inputnumber1 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp1);
        inputnumber2 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp2);
        inputnumber3 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp3);
        inputnumber4 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp4);
        inputnumber5 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp5);
        inputnumber6 = findViewById(R.id.inputotp6);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textmobileshownumber);
        textView.setText(String.format(
                "+91-%s", getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile")
        ));

        verifybuttonclick.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!inputnumber1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputnumber2.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputnumber3.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputnumber4.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputnumber5.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && !inputnumber6.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(verificationOTPtwo.this, "otp verify", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(verificationOTPtwo.this, "Please enter all number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        numberotpmove();

    }

    private void numberotpmove() {

        inputnumber1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    inputnumber2.requestFocus();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        inputnumber2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    inputnumber3.requestFocus();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        inputnumber3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    inputnumber4.requestFocus();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        inputnumber4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    inputnumber5.requestFocus();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        inputnumber5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    inputnumber6.requestFocus();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. check class name that you entered in Intent
2. check your stack trace is there is any error if so then the activity might be crashed due to that.

Thats all I was able to look into your code. if you think still your problem is not resolved then also add verificationOTPtwo.class code too.

Comment: I checked it the class name i entered is correct but still facing the issue i added verificationOTPtwo.class code and the error in logcat please have a look on it @Azira

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are using the wrong id of the button in **verificationOTPtwo**. That's why it's throwing a null pointer exception.

```
Button verifybuttonclick = findViewById(R.id.buttongetotp);
```